# How to keep the reference after serialise and deserialise in Java?

Tags: java, oop, serialization, reference

If A has a reference to C, and B has a reference to C, how can I serialise the whole thing, so that after deserialise all the references are not lost? 

    `B
    |
    ˅
A-->C`

Comment: It should just work - could you give a [mcve] of it failing?

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance but what is readSerial? Is it a method? If so what class is it a method of?

Comment: @cppbeginner That should be a little mistake. I have changed it to deserialise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is the concept of serializing "the whole thing." In Java, serialization usually operates on an object-by-object basis. If the object being serialized has references to other objects, then (provided they are themselves serializable) these references will also be serialized into the same stream.

In your case, however, the "whole thing" consists (so far as serialization is concerned) of two different object graphs : a has a reference to c, and so does b. If c has no references to either a or b, then serializing c will have no effect on either a or b: c is complete without a or b. But serializing a will include the reference to c, and serializing b will include the reference to c, and there will be no indication that these c's are "the same". When a and b are deserialized, they will each end up with a reference to an object "c", but they won't refer to the *same* instance: they will be two different instances with the same state. Whether it's desirable or not, serialization is a good way to clone objects.

To serialize "the whole thing" you need a single object graph that links all the objects, so that you can serialize the entire graph in one operation.

Comment: That's what I thought, but Jon Skeet's comment suggests we might be missing something?

Comment: This should be the solution. Thank you very much.

Comment: @cpp beginner: I think it does "just work" if you pick the right thing to serialize; but you do have to understand the scope at which the process works.